# how to pass value between two solutions

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 different solutions and I need to pass a data between these two solutions. (one way)

My Solution Details are as follows:

**Solution A**

```
Project1- Web Project
```

**Solution B**

```
 Project2- Web Project
 project3 - class library
```

when button click on Solution A project 1 I need to send data to solution B.

What i did so far.

I added WCF project to communicate these two solutions and add service reference to Solution A project B and for the wcf service i added reference to Solution B project 3.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(string  value)
    {
        Class2 cls = new Class2();
        cls.GetValueService(value);
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }      
}
```

Solution B project 3 i added static variable to get that value.

```
public class Class2
{
    public static string assign { get; set; }
    public string getColour2()
    {
        return assign;
    }

    public string GetValueService(string val)
    {
        assign = val;
        return assign;
    }
}
```

then in Solution B project 2 I'm trying to access this static variable. but it does not work as I expected. I think the problem is creating two separate instances.how can i solve this issue? Can i use event handler? is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What is a `Web Project`?  As far as I can tell you can only create a `Web Site` or a `Web Application`.  If it is a `Web Application` is it WebForms, MVC, Web API, etc?

Comment: @ErikPhilips sorry.. its asp.net web application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static variable exists once per **App Domain**. You cannot simply access it from another process.

What you are trying to do is called **Inter-process communication** and there are various ways to do it. As a start, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Answer (score 0):

I would set up an SQL database, store the data in the first solution and then retrieve it in the second.

The benefits are:

- Simplicity and readability as you will reduce coupling.
- Expandability as you can have hundreds of solutions calling from the one database.
- Your data is universal because you can export to XML.
- You can track data changes in real time.
- You can edit your data manually for testing purposes.
- Your data can be read and written by both solutions.

I won't go into a SQL tutorial here because there are already plenty of resources for that.
SQL express is free and has a limit of 2GB per database so you have a heap of space for everything.

Good luck.

Comment: A database is bad for communication since the recipient is not easily notified.

Comment: Why would a recipient need to be notified?

Comment: So you don't have to do polling (checking if new data is available)

Comment: No you just need to bind the element to the data. Then it will update automatically whenever the element is refreshed. If you need an element to auto update just have it do it every 60 seconds or so.

Comment: Binding does not help. The data must be loaded from the database in regular intervals which is a bad way to communicate.

Comment: As far as I see he is not using  the data transfer to do things on a regular basis. He is not streaming data he is simply accessing another project's relatively static data. For this reason it is better to have the higher overhead of data binding to a data base than to risk possible deadlocks with an IPC.